# Inequality involving the sup of a function and its first and second derivatives

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function. And let 
$$\eqalign{   & M_0  = \sup \left|f(x)\right|  \cr 
              & M_1  = \sup \left|\frac{d}{dx} f(x) \right|  \cr 
              & M_2  = \sup \left|\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(x) \right| \cr }$$
Prove that 
$$M_1 ^2  \leqslant 4M_0 M_2$$
I can not think how I can relate these values ​​in some inequality )=

Comment: Oh sorry , I did it <.< !!

Comment: That's great August! When that happens, it is perfectly acceptable to post your own answer below, so that others may learn how to do the problem!

Comment: Oh no , sorry again , im the more stupid guy in the world <.< , what i did is wrong, sorry <.<.<<<.<

Comment: One should maybe remark here that the question implicitly assumes $M_0$ to be finite (or that $\infty\cdot 0=\infty$), because otherwise we can take $f (x)=x$, for which the inequality would read $1=M_0 \leq 4\cdot M_0 M_2= 4\cdot \infty \cdot 0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX: not only, we also have to assume that $f''$ is not identically zero, otherwise for $f(x)=ax+b$ on $(0,1)$ the inequality states $a^2\leq 0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry to leave a comment here, but it's about the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305324 that you marked as duplicate of the present; this is not true; look carefully at the question you marked as duplicate: it is not the Kolmogorov Inequality (please read my comment to math110: the other question is about the max of $|f'|^2/f$, not about the max of $|f'|^2$ divided by the max of $f$).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that $(\sup_{x\in R}|f'(x)|)^2\leq 4\sup_{x\in R}|f(x)|\cdot\sup_{x\in R}|f''(x)|$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019774/proving-that-sup-x-in-rfx2-leq-4-sup-x-in-rfx-cdot-sup-x-in-r)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an exercise in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, if I remember correctly, where it appears with a generous hint. I think the solution alluded to runs as follows.

Fix $x\in\mathbb R$. For $h>0$, you can expand $f(x+2h)$ via Taylor's theorem:
$$
f(x+2h)
=
f(x)+f'(x)2h+\frac{f''(\xi)}{2!}(2h)^2
$$
where $\xi\in(x,x+2h)$. So
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{2h}\left[f(x+2h)-f(x)\right]-f''(\xi)h
$$
From here you can bound $|f'(x)|$:
$$
|f'(x)|\leq\frac{1}{2h}|f(x+2h)-f(x)|+|f''(\xi)|h\leq\frac{M_0}{h}+M_2h.
$$
Since $x$ is arbitrary, you can replace $|f'(x)|$ with $M_1$. If $M_2=0$, let $h\to\infty$ to get $M_1=0$. Otherwise, rearrange to get
$$
0\leq M_2h^2-M_1h+M_0=M_2\left(h-\frac{M_1}{2M_2}\right)^2+\frac{4M_2M_0-M_1^2}{4M_2}.
$$
Take $h=\frac{M_1}{2M_2}$ to get the inequality.

Comment: Remark: we must assume $M_2>0$, since the inequality does not hold for linear functions. Given that, we can just take $h=\sqrt{\frac{M_0}{M_2}}$ in the bound for $|f'(x)|$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well I guess I tacitly assumed that $M_0<\infty$, in which case $M_2=0$ forces $M_1=0$ as the argument shows (and if $M_2>0$ we could just take $h=\sqrt{M_0/M_2}$ as you say, avoiding the algebraic step at the end). But I agree that if we allow $M_0=\infty$ then the inequality won't make sense as stated for $M_2=0$.