# Showing that a function is in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I need to prove the following statement or find a counter-example:
Let $u\in L^1\cap C^2$ with $u''\in L^1$. Then $u'\in L^1$.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove or disprove it, since the $|\bullet|$ in the definition of $L^1$ is giving me huge problems. I found counter-examples if either $u\notin L^1$ or $u''\notin L^1$, but none of them could be generalized to a example that satisfies all the conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is useful to recall the following lemma:

> If $f$ is a twice differentiable function over $I=[a,b]$ and 
>   $$M_0=\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|,\quad M_1=\sup_{x\in I}|f'(x)|,\quad M_2=\sup_{x\in I} |f''(x)|,$$ then $M_1^2\leq 4M_0 M_2$.

It is a well-known exercise from baby Rudin's: you can find a proof of it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71126/inequality-involving-the-sup-of-a-function-and-its-first-and-second-derivatives).

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it gives:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{-M}^{M}|u'(t)|\,dt &\leq& \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sup_{t\in I_k=\left[-M+k\frac{2M}{N},-M+(k+1)\frac{2M}{N}\right]}|u'(t)|\cdot\mu(I_k)\\&\leq& 2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sqrt{\mu(I_k)\sup_{t\in I_k}|u(t)|\cdot \sup_{t\in I_k}|u''(t)|\mu(I_k)}\\&\leq&2\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sup_{t\in I_k}|u(t)|\mu(I_k)\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sup_{t\in I_k}|u''(t)|\mu(I_k)},\end{eqnarray*} $$
so, by letting $N\to +\infty$, we have that the $L^1$-norm of $u'(t)$ on $[-M,M]$ is bounded by twice the geometric mean of the $L^1$-norms of $u(t)$ and $u''(t)$ on the same interval. This proves the claim.

Comment: ... and I have just discovered this is a basic case of the Gagliardo-Niremberg interpolation inequality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality).

Comment: Nice proof. Small remark: I think you forgot to multiply with the length of the "small" intervals in your first step (and also in the later steps), i.e. with something like $2M/N$. After all, you are discrediting the integral, so you should get something like a sum of "value on $I_k$" times "length of $I_k$".

Comment: @PhoemueX: you are right, now fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer and the nice proof!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Don't you need twice continuously differentiable for the lemma?

Comment: @Freeze_S: for the lemma, twice differentiable with bounded derivatives is enough. Obviously, $C^2$ is enough for not caring too much about the minimum requirements.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: But I meant continuously differentiable because it may have not even measurable second derivative, or?