# Show that $\sup_{x \in [-a, a]}|f'(x)| \le \frac{\sup_{x \in [-a, a]}|f(x)|}{a} + \sup_{x \in [-a, a]}\frac{|f''(x)|(x^2 + a^2)}{2a}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable on $[-a, a]$.

Show that:

$$\sup_{x \in [-a, a]}|f'(x)| \le \frac{\sup_{x \in [-a, a]}|f(x)|}{a} + \sup_{x \in [-a, a]}\frac{|f''(x)|(x^2 + a^2)}{2a}$$

I think it is somehow related to Taylor polynomial $x \to x_0$

$$ f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f''(x_0)(x - x_0)^2}{2} $$

Comment: This is a variation on a well-known exercise in Baby Rudin that is a useful introduction to the Gagliardo-Niremberg inequality. Have a look at this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095378/showing-that-a-function-is-in-l1

Comment: Actually, you just need to tweak a bit Nick Strehlke's solution here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71126/inequality-involving-the-sup-of-a-function-and-its-first-and-second-derivatives