# Show that if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and $f''$ is bounded, then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, limits

I'm trying to answer the following exercise: Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable on $[0,+\infty)$.

> Show that if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and $f''$ is bounded, then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)=0$.
>   If $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)$ exists then I know how to prove that this limit is equal to 0 (by using the mean value theorem).
>
> But how can I show that this limit exists?

**Counterexample:** Let us consider  $f(x) = x \sin\frac{1}{x}$. Then $$f'(x) = \sin\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x} \cos\frac{1}{x}$$ and $$f''(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}\cos\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}\cos\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} \sin\frac{1}{x}.$$ This example shows that the hypothesis that there exists $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is essential.

Comment: This claim is known as Barbalat's Lemma

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for this comment!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396707/if-fx-to-0-as-x-to-infty-and-f-is-bounded-show-that-fx-to0-as-x).

Comment: The question here is different. I want to prove that the limit of $f'(x)$ exists using the boundedness of $f''$. In this link the existence of this limit is hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks, David Mitra

Comment: A key lemma is outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1095422/44121), too.

Answer (score 3):

We are given that $f''$ is bounded, so let
$$
|f''(x)|\le M\tag1
$$
Suppose that
$$
\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}|f'(x)|=A\tag2
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, there is an $L$ so that if $x,y\ge L$,
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{A^2}{8M}\tag3
$$

By $(2)$, there is an $x_0\ge L+\frac{A}{2M}$ so that $|f'(x_0)|\gt\frac A2$. Then, by $(1)$, $|f'(x)|\ge\frac A2-M|x-x_0|$. Since $f'$ has the same sign over $\left[x_0-\frac{A}{2M},x_0+\frac{A}{2M}\right]$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,f\left(x_0+\frac{A}{2M}\right)-f\left(x_0-\frac{A}{2M}\right)\,\right|
&=\left|\,\int_{x_0-\frac{A}{2M}}^{x_0+\frac{A}{2M}}f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&=\int_{x_0-\frac{A}{2M}}^{x_0+\frac{A}{2M}}\left|f'(x)\right|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\ge\int_{x_0-\frac{A}{2M}}^{x_0+\frac{A}{2M}}\left(\frac A2-M|x-x_0|\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{A^2}{4M}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
However, the only way that $(3)$ and $(4)$ do not contradict is if $A=0$. That is,
$$
\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}|f'(x)|=0\tag5
$$
which implies
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0}\tag6
$$

---

**Finiteness of $A$**

Note that since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, there is an $M_2$ so that for $x\ge M_2$, $|f(x)-f(x+1)|\le1$. The Mean Value Theorem says that for some $\xi\in(x,x+1)$, $|f'(\xi)|\le1$. The Mean Value Theorem and $(1)$ say that for any $\zeta\in(x,x+1)$, $|f'(\zeta)-f'(\xi)|\le M$. Therefore, the $\limsup$ mentioned in $(2)$ is finite; in fact, it is bounded by $M+1$.

Comment: How do you prove the existence of $A$?

Comment: limsup always exists; it may be infinite, but it exists. I see that in one of my edits, I took out the part that shows it is bounded by $M+1$. I will put that back for clarity.

Comment: Let assume that $A=\infty $ does that not cause any damage to your computation? see that line before $(4)$

Comment: @GuyFsone: why are you worrying about $A=\infty$? I just said I was going to show that $A$ is finite, and I have done so.

Comment: that is ok now thanks +1)

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is twice differentiable,  by Taylor's expansion, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $c_{x,\varepsilon}\in(x,x+\varepsilon)$ such that $$f(x+\varepsilon)=f(x)+f'(x)\varepsilon+\frac{1}{2}f''(c_{x,\varepsilon})\varepsilon^2.$$
But $f''$ is bounded (say, by $ |f''|<2M$), so it follows that
$$|f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)-f'(x)\varepsilon|\le M\varepsilon^2.$$
Therefore, by triangular inequality,
 $$|f'(x)\varepsilon|\le|f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)|+ M\varepsilon^2.$$
But,  $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, so fixing $\varepsilon>0$ and letting $x\to\infty$, we we get 
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}|f'(x)|\le M\varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the conclusion follows.

Comment: This proves that the compose $f' \circ g$, where $g(x)=c_x$, has limit egual to $0$. But does it prove that the limit of $f'$ is $0$? The first equality of the last line is my doubt.

Comment: @Lucas I have proven the existence now see the edit

Comment: @user85353 see the edit I have prove the existence and it still works perfectly