# boundedness of first derivative of $f$

Tags: analysis

I think this problem is kind of a famous problem...

A function $f$ is real valued function from real line.

Suppose that both of the absolute value of $f$ and absolute value of the second derivative of $f$ are bounded by 1.

Then, show that the absolute value of the first derivative of $f$ is bounded by 2.

Are there anyone who can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly refer to [Inequality involving the sup of a function and its first and second derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71126/inequality-involving-the-sup-of-a-function-and-its-first-and-second-derivatives) for a description of the theorem I am about to use.

Using the notation of the previous question if $M_0 = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)|$ and $M_2 = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f''(x)|$ then by the least upper bound property we have
$$ M_0 \leq 1, \ M_2 \leq 1$$
this is because both $|f(x)|$ and $|f''(x)|$ are bounded above by 1. Furthermore if we denote $M_1 = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f'(x)|$ then by virtue of being an upper bound for $|f'(x)| : x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} : |f'(x)| \leq M_1$$
Now combining the two we have
$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} : M_1^2 \leq 4 M_0 M_2 = 4 \implies M_1 \leq 2 \implies |f'(x)| \leq 2$$
As desired.