Is $f'$ bounded if both $f$ and $f''$ are bounded?
I'm reading the monograph "Operateurs pseudo-differentiels et theoreme de Nash-Moser" by Alinhac and Gerard. When working on Page 63 Exercise 2.4(a)

I came up of the following simpler question:
Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. If both $f$ and $f''$ are bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$, is it true that $f'$ must be bounded on $\mathbb{R}$? If not, what is a counterexample?
Edit: we can generalize the problem as follows: Let $f\in C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If both $f$ and $\partial^{\alpha}f$ are bounded for any $|\alpha|=k$. Then $\partial^{\beta}f$ is bounded for any $1\leq |\beta|\leq k-1$. The first part of  Exercise 2.4(a) (and Taylor's formula with integral remainders) shows how to prove it.

Context please [tour]

Could you be more specific about your suggestion?

This has been asked a lot of times

Could you show me a link?

Perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38811/27978 ?

Thank you very much!

Here is another answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549141/bound-on-first-order-derivative
